# Grouping by two parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this structure:

```
id | timestamp | barcode
```

The timestamp is datetime and the barcode is a full barcode, from which I need only the first 9 digits.

I need to get the count for each product for each day with one query.

So I basically need a result like:

```
date       | item number | count
-----------+-------------+--------
12.02.2019 | 827384950   | 32
```

Item number is `left(barcode, 9)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - using `cast()` to convert timestamp to date and then add that in group by

```
select cast([timestamp] as date),left(barcode, 9) as itemnumber,count(*)
from tablename
group by cast([timestamp] as date),left(barcode, 9)
```

Comment: Just 20 seconds late...:)

Comment: Hey, this works perfect! Can I add to my question just so I don't do a new thread for a followup - what would you recommend if I want to group them by `shift` if `shift 1` is `06:00:00 to 14:29:59` in the datetime `timestamp`, `shift 2` is `14:30:00 to 22:59:59`... etc?

Comment: it would be great if you add a separate question @MaximilianBerbechelov

Comment: Okay, doing that :)

Answer (score 0):

this query has better performance

```
select date, itemnumber, count(*) from
(select cast([timestamp] as date) as date,left(barcode, 9) as itemnumber
from tablename) a
group by date,itemnumber
```